# Django - how to save method apply only on new data

Tags: django

How do I manipulate this method to be applied only on new entries and does not have a previous entry.

When in admin, I will add an record, this method is applied correctly. but when I edit the same record, this method is applied again.

```
def save(self):
    p = Product.objects.last()
    if p:
        self.productnumber = 1000 + p.id
    else:
        self.productnumber = 1000
    super(Product, self).save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute some code in the save() method, only for non-existing items you should check if a primary key exists.

```
def save(self):
    if self.pk is None:
        # Code for new objects
    else:
        # Code for existing objects
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways are there.

**1. [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save)**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender= Product)
def my_callback(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        #new
    else:
        #update
```

**2. check primary key exists**

```
def save(self):
    if self.pk: #or id
        #update
    else:
        #new
```